# Servlet->JSP COnversion

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

**I need to convert this servlet into jsp. Confused about the doGet and doPost both method are written in servlet then how to convert/ deal with such kind of scenario in JSP?**

**Do we need to make different jsp pages for doPost and doGet functions? Please indicate using jsp code.**

**Thank You**

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

import javax.servlet.*;

import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class RequestParamExample extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse

response)

throws IOException, ServletException

{

response.setContentType(&quot;text/html&quot;);

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

out.println(&quot;GET Request. No Form Data Posted&quot;);

}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res)

throws IOException, ServletException

{

Enumeration e = request.getParameterNames();

PrintWriter out = res.getWriter ();

while (e.hasMoreElements()) {

String name = (String)e.nextElement();

String value = request.getParameter(name);

out.println(name + &quot; = &quot; + value);

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Servlet you can get the request method (GET, POST,...) with:

```
request.getMethod()
```

Inside a JSP you can do the same with:

```
${pageContext.request.method}
```

An example how to differentiate between the request methods in JSP with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>getMethod</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="Test method: GET"/>
    </form>
    <hr>

    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="p1" value="v1"><br>
        <input type="text" name="p2" value="v2"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Test method: POST"/>
    </form>
    <hr>

    <h4>results:</h4>
    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.method == 'GET'}">
        GET Request. No Form Data Posted
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.method == 'POST'}">
        POST Request. Form Data:<br>
        <c:forEach items="${param}" var="p">
            ${p.key} = "${p.value}"<br>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to split the code in `doPost.jsp` and `doGet.jsp`, replace the last section with the following:

```
<h4>results:</h4>
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.method == 'GET'}">
    <%@include file="doGet.jsp" %>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${pageContext.request.method == 'POST'}">
    <%@include file="doPost.jsp" %>
</c:if>
```